# Is there a reason my program is incapable of sorting corresponding char arrays?

Tags: c++

The task is to create a program that is capable of sorting patient records based on a couple of different categories. I am trying to have it sort by age, which it can do, and have the corresponding values line up in the same order.

It can output `ID`, `lastName`, and `firstName` in the correct order, but when I try to make it output `sex` the same way, it tells me that an argument of type `char` is incompatible with parameter of type `const char *`. I'm not sure why exactly `sex` would be any different from the other variables.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring> // required for string manipulation
#include <iomanip> // required for tabular output

using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    // Provided arrays and constants
    string category;
    int hold;
    char holdstr[10];
    char holdstr2[10];
    char holdstr3[10];
    char holdstr4[10];
    char holdsex[1];
    const int NUM_PATIENTS = 10; // 10 patients will be included, this value cannot be modified
    const int MAX_NAME_LENGTH = 10; // no names longer than 10 characters, this value cannot be modified
    const int ID_LENGTH = 8;
    unsigned int age[NUM_PATIENTS] = {50, 22, 22, 89, 15, 16, 22, 32, 15, 66}; // 1D int array age of each patient
    char id[NUM_PATIENTS][ID_LENGTH + 1] = {"10854893", "10983922", "98333894", "57290888", "14899822", "79278282", "44293822", "62911023", "28399020", "33212322"}; // 1D int array identification #
    char firstName[NUM_PATIENTS][MAX_NAME_LENGTH] = {"allison", "michael", "michael", "johnny", "sabrina", "helen", "ignacio", "melissa", "hassan", "melody"}; // 2D char array: first names for patients
    char lastName[NUM_PATIENTS][MAX_NAME_LENGTH] = {"pratt","xiao", "barkley", "wu", "sappal", "mcdonald", "garza", "tran", "nahas", "baker"}; // 2D char array: last names for patients
    char sex[10][2] = {'f','m','m','m','f','f','m','f','m','f'}; // 1D char array sex of the patient
    //

    // PART 1: Select a primary sorting category from user input
beginning:{
cout << "Please enter the sorting category (Age, ID, First, Last, Sex" << endl;
cin >> category; //collect required category

for (int i=0 ; i <category.size() ; ++i) category[i] = toupper( category[i]); //convert to upper case no matter what
if (category=="AGE")
{
    cout << "Case 1, sorting by age." << endl;
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<10; j++)
        {
            if (age[j]>age [j+1]||age[j]==age[j+1])
            {
                hold=age[j];
                strcpy(holdstr, firstName[j]);
                strcpy(holdstr2,lastName[j]);
                strcpy(holdstr3, id[j]);

                age [j]=age [j+1];
                strcpy(firstName[j], firstName[j+1]);
                strcpy(lastName [j], lastName [j+1]);
                strcpy(id[j],id[j+1]);


                age [j+1]=hold;
                strcpy(firstName[j+1], holdstr);
                strcpy(lastName[j+1],holdstr2);
                strcpy(id[j+1],holdstr3);
            }
        }
    }
}
else if (category=="ID")
{
    cout << "Case 2, sorting by ID."<< endl;
}
else if (category=="FIRST")
{
    cout << "Case 3, sorting by first name." << endl;
}
else if (category=="LAST")
{
    cout << "Case 4, sorting by last name." << endl;
}
else if (category=="SEX")
{
    cout << "Case 5, sorting by sex" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "Invalid input" << endl;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(100,'\n');
    goto beginning;
}


    // PART 3/4: Sorting patient records


    // PART 2: Outputting patient records to terminal in tabular form
cout << setw(10) << "Age" << setw(10) << age [0] << setw(10) << age [1]<< setw(10)<< age [2]<< setw(10) << age [3] << setw(10) << age [4] << setw(10) << age [5] << setw(10)<< age [6] << setw(10)<< age [7] << setw(10) << age [8] << setw(10) << age [9] << setw(10) <<endl;
cout << setw(10) << "ID"<< setw(10) << id [0] << setw(10) << id [1]<< setw(10)<< id [2]<< setw(10) << id [3] << setw(10) << id [4] << setw(10) << id [5] << setw(10)<< id [6] << setw(10)<< id [7] << setw(10) << id [8] << setw(10) << id [9] << setw(10) <<endl;
cout << setw(10) << "First Name" << setw(10) << firstName [0] << setw(10) << firstName [1]<< setw(10)<< firstName [2]<< setw(10) << firstName [3] << setw(10) << firstName [4] << setw(10) << firstName [5] << setw(10)<< firstName [6] << setw(10)<< firstName [7] << setw(10) << firstName [8] << setw(10) << firstName [9] << setw(10) <<endl;
cout << setw(10) << "Last Name" << setw(10) << lastName [0] << setw(10) << lastName [1]<< setw(10)<< lastName [2]<< setw(10) << lastName [3] << setw(10) << lastName [4] << setw(10) << lastName [5] << setw(10)<< lastName [6] << setw(10)<< lastName [7] << setw(10) << lastName [8] << setw(10) << lastName [9] << setw(10) <<endl;
cout << setw(10) << "Sex" << setw(10) << sex [0] << setw(10) << sex [1]<< setw(10)<< sex [2]<< setw(10) << sex [3] << setw(10) << sex [4] << setw(10) << sex [5] << setw(10)<< sex [6] << setw(10)<< sex[7] << setw(10) << sex [8] << setw(10) << sex [9] << setw(10) <<endl;
return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: @leialeia In this statement strcpy(holdsex, sex[j]); the expression sex[j] has the type char. You may not use it as an argument of strcpy

Comment: `strcpy()` copies a *null-terminated string*, but `sex[j]` is a single `char` not a string, unlike your other inputs which are strings. Change `strcpy(holdsex, sex[j]);` to `holdsex[0] = sex[j]; holdsex[1] = '\0';` Or else change your `sex` array to `char sex[NUM_PATIENTS][2] = {"f", ...};` instead.

Comment: This code is all wrong.  Use a `struct` (let's call it `patient`) to represent a patient, and use `std::string` for (most of) the individual pieces of information that you want to store for each `patient`.  Then use `std::vector<patient>` to create your list of patients and you're done.

Comment: @PaulSanders and `std::sort()` to sort the `std::vector<patient>` by the desired criteria

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ah yes, forgot that bit :)

Comment: @RemyLebeau if I change it to char sex [NUM_PATIENTS][2] it just spews hundreds of Ms and Fs

Comment: @leialeia -- The better way you sort these items is *not* to sort the original arrays, but to sort an index array instead.  Then you use that index array to point to the items.  If you look at your code, it is very clumsy, even if a professional were to take your approach.  Imagine if you had 20 other arrays associated with your data -- would you write 20 sets of "swap" code, multiplied by the number of different sort orders?  You will go insane trying to keep up with that.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie at this point I'm really just trying to get my code to work so I can hand in SOMETHING

Comment: @leialeia [See this example](https://godbolt.org/z/P5Mo99zbM).  I won't post this as an answer, but just to let you know the other approach I mentioned.

Comment: @leialeia "*if I change it to `char sex [NUM_PATIENTS][2]` it just spews hundreds of Ms and Fs*" - then you likely didn't adjust the rest of your code to handle the array's new data type

Comment: _at this point I'm really just trying to get my code to work_ That's not a great strategy.  It needs rewriting, no matter how much time pressure you're under.  Can you ask for a bit more time?

Answer (score 2):

You have attempted this using a [Structure of Arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AoS_and_SoA#:%7E:text=to%20memory%20coalescing.-,Software%20support,support%20a%20data%2Doriented%20design) approach. You should aim for an Array of Structures approach. From wikipedia:

> Array of structures (AoS) is the opposite (and more conventional) layout, in which data for different fields is interleaved. **This is often more intuitive, and supported directly by most programming languages**.

*Text formatting is by me*

So, lets look at your example. First lets simplify, we have a patient right:

```
Patient
  - name
  - age
  - id
```

Lets just consider these fields for now. We can easily make a struct to represent this:

```
struct Patient {
   std::string name;  // std::string is for c++ and much easier to use than a char array
   unsigned age;
   int id;
};
```

Now we can have an array of patients as you have done, like this:

```
Patient patients[NUM_PATIENTS] = {{"bob", 20, 1}, ...};
```

But this sucks, what if we want to add a new patient? We can't, we have to know in advance how many we have. So c++ has the solution! `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<Patient> patients = {{"bob", 20, 1}, ...};
patients.push_back(Patient{"ann", 35, 52});
```

Now to sort them is very easy! c++ gives us `std::sort`! All we need is a way to compare. Lets take age for example:

```
auto age_compare = [](const Patient& lhs, const Patient& rhs) { 
    return lhs.age < rhs.age;
}
```

This is a lambda. A special little inline function that you can use. For example, image we have bob and ann from the above example. Bob is 20, ann is 35, so we can do:

```
age_compare(bob, ann); // This will be true because bob is younger than ann.
```

With that we can sort our vector!

```
std::sort(std::begin(patients), std::end(patients), age_compare);
```

How easy is that!